# How access form fields using javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="f['cart']]['product_name']"/>
</form>
```

How can I access textfield's value using javascript?

Comment: `name` on `<form>` is a legacy attribute that only exists for backwards compatibility with truly ancient browsers. Use `id` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the form from the forms collection, then the input from said form's elements collection.

```
document.forms['myForm'].elements["f['cart']]['product_name']"]
```

Comment: My apologies, the code I was testing was embedded in a CMS which was  changing the form name at run time I found.  It does work perfectly.